# Loss function for OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I have a `OneVsRestClassifier` (`scikit-learn`) which has been trained.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(C=1.2, penalty='l1')).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I want to find out the loss for my test data. I used `log_loss` function but it does not seem to work because I have multiple classes as outputs for each test case. What do I do?

Comment: How big is your data and which dataset are you using?

Comment: I am using 'reuters' dataset from ntlk.corpus. Almost around 10,000 documents in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classification problem that you are referring to is known as a [Multi-Label Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) problem. You have made a good decision of using the `OneVsRestClassifier` for this purpose. By default the [`score`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.score) method uses the **subset accuracy** which is a very harsh metric as it requires you to guess the entire subset of labels correctly.

Some other loss functions, provided by scikit-learn, that you can use are as follows:

1. [**Hamming Loss**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#hamming-loss) - This measures the hamming distance between your prediction of labels and the true label. [This](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/HammingLoss) is an intuitive formula to understand the hamming distance.
2. [**Jaccard Similarity Coefficient Score**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#jaccard-similarity-coefficient-score) - This measures the Jaccard similarity between your predicted labels and the true labels.
3. [**Precision, Recall and F-Measures**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) - In the case of multi-label classification, the notion of Precision, Recall and F-Measures can be applied to each class independently. The [following guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification) explains how to combine them across all labels in multi-label classification.

If you need to also rank the labels as it is done in multi-label ranking problems, then there are other more advanced techniques available in scikit-learn which are very well documented with examples [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multilabel-ranking-metrics). If you are dealing with this kind of a problem, then let me know in the comments, I will explain each of these metrics in more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Could you please mark this as an accepted answer if it helped you?  This will also help other people who have the same doubt. Thank you.